# C: How do I add up numbers in a row and then add them to the end?

Tags: c

So I already have a 2D (square) array of random integers, but I need to make a function to add up each row, then put that sum in the last column. 
Kind of like: (Just using random number here. As I said, it generates a random matrix.)

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 
9 1 2 0
```

Needs to be:

```
1 2 3 10
5 6 7 26 
9 1 2 12
```

So far I have this:

```
void newmatrix(int array[][], int sizeofmatrix)
{
     int row, col; 
     int sum = 0; 
     for(col = 0; col < size; col++)
     { 
         for(row = 0; row < size; row++)
         {
             sum += array[row][col];
         } 
      } 
  }
```

Do I have the right idea? And how do I proceed?

Comment: Your example arrays are not square.

Comment: Exchange the for loops, after the then inner loop set the last value of the current row to the sum.

Comment: Can you re-explain? I think the wording is confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming square matrix) Modify your code like that:

```
void newmatrix(int array[][], int sizeofmatrix)
{
     int row,col; 
     int sum; 
     for(row = 0; row < sizeofmatrix; row++)
     { 
         sum=0; // sum should be initialized to 0 for each row
         for(col = 0; col < sizeofmatrix; col++)
         {
             sum += array[row][col];
         } 
         array[row][col-1]=sum; // Add the sum in last col
      } 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense